# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any of the following names:gazeboConfig.cmake gazebo-config.cmake

Tags: cmake

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What should I do to solve this problem?[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17187/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22gazebo%22-with-any---of-the-following-names:gazeboconfig.cmake-----gazebo-config.cmake/) by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GORO_CHAT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6027/goro_chat/) on 2018-07-22**:
Same issue......I have even installed Libgazebo5-dev ...but same error....Can anybody help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Which version of gazebo is installed? Find out using `gazebo --version`. For example, I have gazebo 7.

```
$ gazebo --version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.7.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
```

You'll need the the dev package for that version of gazebo. For gazebo 7 run `sudo apt install libgazebo7-dev`.

You can find more information about  setting up a computer to build plugins in the first few sections of this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i5&cat=.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on 2017-09-07**:
I have solved this problem by following the installation tutorial, and 'sudo' the basic files. Thank you for your help.

**Comment by [GORO_CHAT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6027/goro_chat/) on 2018-07-22**:
I have installed Libgaebo5-dev but still the error is same.  What could be the reason?

**Comment by [GORO_CHAT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6027/goro_chat/) on 2018-07-22**:
Even after installing libgazebo4-dev,  the error remained the same on indigo ros+Gazebo 5

**Comment by [desmond13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8998/desmond13/) on 2022-11-24**:
I had the same issue and followed the one liner installation and got it to work:
https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install